# If the output of a model is a ridge function, what should the activation functions at all the nodes be?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, gradient-descent, activation-functions

I have the following assignment.

[image]

I can't understand the b part of this question in my assignment. I have completed the 1st part and understand the maths behind it, but the 2nd part has me stumped.

I looked up ridge functions and they basically map real vectors to a single real value, from what I understood. For that reason, I considered that the activation function has to be one that ranges over the real numbers, but that still doesn't clear my doubts.

I don't need a full answer just an explanation of the question will be very helpful, here's some text from the book I'm referring( Russel and Norvig), though I couldn't really grasp how this would help me choose an activation function.

> Before delving into learning rules, let us look at the ways in which networks generate complicated functions. First, remember that each unit in a sigmoid network represents a soft threshold in its input space, as shown in Figure 18.17(c) (page 726). With one hidden layer and one output layer, as in Figure 18.20(b), each output unit computes a soft-thresholded linear combination of several such functions. For example, by adding two opposite-facing soft threshold functions and thresholding the result, we can obtain a “ridge” function as shown in Figure 18.23(a). Combining two such ridges at right angles to each other (i.e., combining the outputs from four hidden units), we obtain a “bump” as shown in Figure 18.23(b).